# How to install Oozie 3.3.1 on Hadoop 1.1.1?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am running Hadoop Ver 1.1.1 and want to install Oozie 3.3.1 while installing I am getting following error

```
hduseros@MT2012018:/usr/local/oozie-3.3.1$ ./distro/target/oozie-3.3.1-distro/oozie-3.3.1/bin/oozie-setup.sh -hadoop 1.1.1 /usr/local/hadoop -extjs /usr/local/oozie-3.3.1/webapp/src/main/webapp/ext-2.2.zip
  setting CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx1024m"


Exiting: Unsupported Hadoop version '', supported versions: 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.104, 0.20.200, 0.23.x and 2.x
```

I am following this tutorial
http://practicalcloudcomputing.com/post/26337621577/installing-and-running-apache-oozie-3-2-x-and-possibly?543b50f0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before running this oozie-setup.sh, you need to copy the required jars of hadoop 1.1.1 into libext directory in oozie home. then run the above command.

http://srikanthayalasomayajulu.blogspot.sg/2013/02/apache-oozie-331-installation-on-apache.html

follow this link...hope this should be helpful

Comment: Can we install it on Hadoop 1.1.1?