# Oozie war creation - Unsupported Hadoop version supported versions: 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.104, 0.20.200, 0.23.x and 2.x

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am trying to install oozie 3.3.2 on hadoop 1.0.3 ,I am unable to create oozie.war  .I am following the instructions present in 
http://venkatrequiescence.blogspot.in/2012/12/oozie-installation.html.When i wxecute the following command i get- Unsupported Hadoop version supported versions: 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.104, 0.20.200, 0.23.x and 2.x

./$OOZIE_HOME/distro/target/oozie-3.3.2/oozie/bin/oozie-setup.sh -hadoop 1.0.3 / -extjs /Users/hadoop/ext-2.2.zip.

I have even tried to fix this by looking at the solution given at following link but i am unable to fix the issue as the article given in the solution isn't very clear ,Kindly help me out

[How to install Oozie 3.3.1 on Hadoop 1.1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611421/how-to-install-oozie-3-3-1-on-hadoop-1-1-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i don't know whether this will `work` at runtime, but you can just manually list the hadoop jars via the `-jar` option rather than via `-hadoop`:

```
./oozie-setup.sh -jars /opt/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.3/hadoop-core-1.0.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.3/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/opt/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.3/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/opt/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.3/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar
```

If you look at the `addtowar.sh` script (which is where this error message originates), you can see a set of conditional jars to include based upon the version of hadoop specified via the `-hadoop` option:

```
#get the list of hadoop jars that will be injected based on the hadoop version
function getHadoopJars() {
  version=$1
  if [ "${version}" = "0.20.1" ]; then
    #List is separated by ":"
    hadoopJars="hadoop-core*.jar"
  elif [ "${version}" = "0.20.2" ]; then
    #List is separated by ":"
    hadoopJars="hadoop-core*.jar"
  elif [ "${version}" = "0.20.104" ]; then
    #List is separated by ":"
    hadoopJars="hadoop-core*.jar:jackson-core-asl-*.jar:jackson-mapper-asl-*.jar"
  elif [ "${version}" = "0.20.200" ]; then
    #List is separated by ":"
    hadoopJars="hadoop-core*.jar:jackson-core-asl-*.jar:jackson-mapper-asl-*.jar:commons-configuration-*.jar"
  elif [[ "${version}" =~ .*23 ]]; then
    suffix="-[0-9.]*"
    #List is separated by ":"
    hadoopJars="hadoop-mapreduce-client-core${suffix}.jar:hadoop-mapreduce-client-common${suffix}.jar:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient${suffix}.jar:hadoop-mapreduce-client-app${suffix}.jar:hadoop-yarn-common${suffix}.jar:hadoop-yarn-api${suffix}.jar:hadoop-hdfs${suffix}.jar:hadoop-common${suffix}.jar:hadoop-auth${suffix}.jar:guava*.jar:protobuf-*.jar:avro-ipc-*.jar:jackson-core-asl-*.jar:jackson-mapper-asl-*.jar:commons-configuration-*.jar"
  elif [[ "${version}" =~ 2.* ]]; then
    suffix="-[0-9.]*"
    #List is separated by ":"
    hadoopJars="hadoop-mapreduce-client-core${suffix}.jar:hadoop-mapreduce-client-common${suffix}.jar:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient${suffix}.jar:hadoop-mapreduce-client-app${suffix}.jar:hadoop-yarn-common${suffix}.jar:hadoop-yarn-api${suffix}.jar:hadoop-yarn-client${suffix}.jar:hadoop-hdfs${suffix}.jar:hadoop-common${suffix}.jar:hadoop-auth${suffix}.jar:guava*.jar:protobuf-*.jar:jackson-core-asl-*.jar:jackson-mapper-asl-*.jar:commons-configuration-*.jar:commons-cli-*.jar"
  else
    echo
    echo "Exiting: Unsupported Hadoop version '${hadoopVer}', supported versions: 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.104, 0.20.200, 0.23.x and 2.x"
    echo
    cleanUp
    exit -1;
  fi
}
```

So seeing as 1.0.x isn't in the list, you can look at the 0.20.104 or 0.20.200 version and just use the same jars from 1.0.3:

- hadoop-core-1.0.3
- lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
- lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar
- lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar

I don't see why it won't work (oozie just needs to communicate with the mapred and hdfs services), but you may have issues at runtime - worth a try (i have tried this with 3.1.3-incubating and didn't have any problems with the small amount of testing i did)

Comment: Thanks Chris,I added one more condition in  getHadoopJars() method to consider hadoop 1.0.3 version and it worked fine.